# Addition of complex number adds 0000000000001j

Tags: python

I am using windows os and python 3.6,

```
test = 10+3.14j
test = test + 1j
print (test)
```

while executing the above code, I get following output
`(10+4.140000000000001j)` --> why this 0000000000001j is getting added.

Comment: Due to rounding errors with floating point numbers.

Comment: Adding one isn't the issue. Look at the value of `test` immediately after the first assignment.